# Como faço para colocar um método de trocar a senha no meu sistema de login usando ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

O meu sistema de login foi feita da seguinte maneira:

Na página inicial do meu site, a gente tem:

```
insira o código aqui`<div class="tab-1 resp-tab-content" aria-labelledby="tab_item-0">
                            <div class="facts">
                            <div class="register">
                                    <form action="logado.php" method="post">            
                                    <input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" required="">                        
                <input name="senha" placeholder="Senha" type="password" required="">                                        
                <div class="sign-up">
                        <input type="submit" value="Entrar"/>
                                    </div>
                                    </form>
                                    </div>
                                    </div> 
                                    </div>
```

depois, o resto do login é feito no arquivo logado.php:

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['email']))
     {
        
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $senha = sha1($_POST['senha']);
        
        include("conectar.php");
        
        $sql = "select nome, senha as 'senha', cpf 
                from clientes 
                where email='$email'";
        
        //echo "$sql";
        
        $resultado = $conexao->query($sql);
        
        if($resultado->num_rows > 0)
        {
            $linha     = $resultado->fetch_object();
            
            $senhaBD = $linha->senha;
            $nome    = $linha->nome;
            $cpf    = $linha->cpf;
            
            if($senha == $senhaBD)
            {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['logado'] = "sim";
                $_SESSION['nome']   = $nome;
                $_SESSION['cpf']   = $cpf;

                
                header("location:index.php");
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-warning">
                        <strong>Aviso!</strong> Senha ou Email inválido!
                     </div>';
                echo "<a href='index.php'>Voltar</a>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-warning">
                        <strong>Aviso!</strong> Senha ou Email inválido!
                     </div>';
                echo "<a href='index.php'>Voltar</a>";
        }
     }
     else
     {
       echo"erro";
     }

   
  
    
?>
```

Como faço para criar um método de trocar a senha usando o Ajax, caso o usuário tenha esquecido a senha?

Answer (score 0):

Voce tem que fazer uma tabela para salvar as solicitações de troca de senha

essa tabela seria algo assim

trocasDeSenhas

- id
- user_id
- codigo_secreto
- data

ao solicitar a troca de senha o sistema gera um codigo aleatorio e cria uma nova entrada nessa tabela

depois envia um email para o proprietário da conta dizendo "bora resetar a senha? lalala"  e nesse email tem um link pro seu sistema e na url vc coloca um parametro com o codigo secreto

mostra um formulario de redefinição de senha pro user_id

mas na moral faz isso só pra estudar, quando for fazer alguma coisa séria tem uma porção de frameworks que abstraem essa parte

paz